# Transposing a pandas dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that currently looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
raw_data = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SP':[35.6,56.7,41,41],'1M':[-7.8,56,56,-3.4],'3M':[24,-31,53,5]}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['Series_Date','SP','1M','3M'])
print df
```

I would like to transponse in a way such that all the value fields get transposed to the Value Column and the date is appended as a row item. The column name of the value field becomes a row for the Description column. That is the resulting Dataframe should look like this:

```
import numpy as np
raw_data = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-14','2017-03-14','2017-03-15','2017-03-15','2017-03-15'],'Value':[35.6,-7.8,24,56.7,56,-31,41,56,53,41,-3.4,5],'Desc':['SP','1M','3M','SP','1M','3M','SP','1M','3M','SP','1M','3M']}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['Series_Date','Value','Desc'])
print df
```

Could someone please help how I can flip and transpose my DataFrame this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to transform `DF` from a wide format to a long one:

```
idx = "Series_Date"              # identifier variable
pd.melt(df, id_vars=idx, var_name="Desc").sort_values(idx).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

Comment: how we can do the other way around! @Nickil